# Google maps api - как выделить объект (реки, озера, моря)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Задача стоит следующая - необходимо, по клику на карте выделить географический объект на карте, интересуют исключительно водные объекты (реки, озера, моря) и сохранить объект как-то в бд. Возможно ли это сделать? Может кто сталкивался с таким? Или может кто то посоветует другое Api, не google maps? Любая другая идея приветствуется.

Comment: гугл вроде как только растр предоставляет. у OpenStreetMap есть векторный сервис (WFS это называется). но чтобы ее подключить в Андроид - надо заморочиться.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если они выделены на карте как обьекты то да .если это просто карта без выделений каких либо обьектов то как вы сохраните ни как.